# SQL Server check constraint

Tags: sql-server, constraints

I have a table in my database and I did a: Script table as > Create to > query editor and some of my columns have this code:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [ConstraintName] FOREIGN KEY([ColumnName])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ForeignKeyTable] ([ColumnName])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName] CHECK CONSTRAINT [ConstraintName2]
GO
```

What does the second constraint do? Other columns in the table only have the first constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second constraint turns on (activates) the check constraint. It is just template code from SSMS

It is possible to generate the `create check constraints` snippet with or without activating it (e.g. nocheck) - so that is itself one of 2 snippets.  Because you opted for the constraints to end up activated, SSMS follows with the activation, not really caring if it was activated already or not.  It doesn't really hurt and is just something SSMS does

Comment: I see so just in case the first one was created and not set to active the second one catches it?

Comment: @William Yes. The script generation fragments in SSMS are many, it just puts together bits and pieces of templates.